# Console not showing results

Tags: terminal, console

Since I've installed Docker, my terminal hasn't been showing anything when I run my codes... it's happening with JavaScript (doesnt read the console.log), with Python (doesnt read the prints). I've uninstalled Docker, Node (and reinstalled it), and sincerely dont know what could be the problem.
The image below shows what happens when I run the code on the console - it juust jumps to another line whithout showing any results:
[image]